# eliminate everything after two ^ characters only in one colum

Tags: bash, awk

[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMfRe.png)

Hello,
I have this data separated by tab.
In the transcripts column I want to delete everything after the second occurrence of the character ^ only in that column

I tried

```
awk -F_ 'NF> 3 {$ 0 = $ 1 FS $ 3 FS $ 5} 1'
```

but delete all the data from the other columns

Comment: Please don't expect readers to goto an external site to understand your question. You should edit your Question to inclue the smallest amount of data needed to illustrate the problem. This means if your record is more than 5 columns wide, (or 60 chars0 you should edit your data to fit on the screen so readers and easily copy/paste into their environment. Use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on mouse-selected text to format correctly as data/code/error messages. Good luck.

Comment: I tried to format your code as code, and now I notice you have spaces separating your `$` and `0`, etc chars. If that is really what your code looks like, it will not work. You want `$0`, etc. Good luck.

Comment: Cesar, please can you tag your question 'awk' as well?

Answer (score 2):

If we care about only one column, and the transcript column is column #1 then:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' -v t=1 '
    match($t, /\^[^^]*\^/) { $t = substr($t, RSTART, RLENGTH) } 1
'
```

Instead of using a regular expression directly, we use the result of the `match()` to trigger our action.  The side effect of `match()` is to set `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`... which is the very thing we need for `substr()` to isolate our pattern for us.

Comment: smart and elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

You want to find a substring in the first field that you don't want to delete:
A string without a `^` (given by `[^^]*` where the first `^` stands for NOT),
followed by a `^` (escaped), and again `[^^]*\^`.
This string will be remembered/restored by `\1`, the remaining part until `\t` will be deleted.

```
sed -r 's/([^^]*\^[^^]*\^)[^\t]*/\1/' datafile
```

When not all lines have two `^` in the first field, you can change this to

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t^]*\^[^\t^]*\^)[^\t]*/\1/' datafile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ text="TRINITY_DN686_c0_g1_i6^YJHO_YEAST^IKS1_YEAST\tcolumn2\tcolumn3\tcolumn4"
$ echo -e ${text} | awk '{ i = index($0, "\t"); split($1, a, "^"); print a[1]"^"a[2] substr($0, i) }'
TRINITY_DN686_c0_g1_i6^YJHO_YEAST   column2 column3 column4
```

- `i = index($0, "\t")` - get the index of the first tab
- `split($1, a, "^")` - split the first column by the caret symbol and store the elements in the array
- `print a[1]"^"a[2] substr($0, i)` - print first and second element from the array and the rest of the columns